# Populate Multiple Select Controls with the Same Values using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-select

I have two select controls that I want to populate with the exact same options.

I started with the following code (which does not work):

```
var result = // raw <option></option> html from ajax call

$("#selImbServiceType").html(result);
$("#selRemitImbServiceType").html(result);
```

If I comment out either of the statements above then the one left works, but when they are both uncommented only the first one works.

Then I changed the code to the following (this works as expected):

```
var result = // raw <option></option> html from ajax call

$("#selImbServiceType,#selRemitImbServiceType").html(result);
```

The second version populates both controls.

I am using jQuery 1.4.4 with Firefox 5.0.1

Any idea why the first version does not work?

**result variable HTML**

Here is the contents of the result variable:

```
<option value="27b3dc65-d60c-46e3-8d9c-bdffad8bc25f">Return To Sender</option>
<option value="bcf435c9-d197-4a54-8d90-f4507c2ac505">Shred And Return Electronically</option>
```

**Surrounding HTML**

```
<div style="overflow:auto;width:100%;">
  <div style="float:left;width:50%">
    <span class="dialogControlLabel">Client</span>
    <br />
    <select id="listClients" onchange="clientSelectionChanged()"></select>
    <span id="spanClientsLoading" style="display:none;"><img src="/Theme/Images/ajax-loader-fb.gif" alt="loading" width="16" height="11" /></span>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span class="dialogControlLabel">IMB Service Type</span>
    <br />
    <select id="selImbServiceType" name="imbServiceType"></select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span class="dialogControlLabel">Stream Name</span>
    <br />
    <input id="txtStreamName" type="text" maxlength="128" name="streamName" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <span class="dialogControlLabel">Processor Module</span>
    <br />
    <input id="txtProcessorModule" type="text" maxlength="256" name="processorModule"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span class="dialogControlLabel">Advanced Location Logic Enabled</span>
    <br />
    <select id="selAdvancedLocationLogicEnabled" name="advancedLocationLogicEnabled">
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span class="dialogControlLabel">Force Mail Enabled</span>
    <br />
    <select id="selForceMailEnabled" name="forceMailEnabled">
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="float:right;width:50%">
    <span class="dialogControlLabel">File Stream Configuration</span>
    <br />
    <select id="selFileStreamConfig"></select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span class="dialogControlLabel">Remit IMB Service Type</span>
    <br />
    <select id="selRemitImbServiceType" name="remitImbServiceType"></select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span class="dialogControlLabel">NCOA Enabled</span>
    <br />
    <select id="selNcoaEnabled" name="ncoaEnabled">
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span class="dialogControlLabel">Skip Logic Enabled</span>
    <br />
    <select id="selSkipLogicEnabled" name="skipLogicEnabled">
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span class="dialogControlLabel">Active</span>
    <br />
    <select id="selActive" name="active">
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you meant to be missing the period before the `html` in the second line?

Comment: Oops, no that was a typo in the question.

Comment: We could do with seeing your HTML as well as your jQuery. [Your code works fine for me in this jsFiddle I created](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/Lfb6A/1/), by the way.

Comment: Ideally, you should use [`$.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/). BTW are you sure result does not contain any broken html?

Comment: @Dana Your actual data [works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/Lfb6A/4/), too. You didn't try to hardcode the data (which has double quotes) as a string wrapped with double quotes, for testing in my example, did you? Because no, that won't work. But it seems unlikely to be your actual problem in the real code.

Comment: @Matt Gibson: Yes, I spoke too soon about the jsFiddle, I had a mismatched quote in there at first when it didn't work.

Comment: It's possible it's an issue with the HTML of your page. Can you provide enough of the page source to show the two `select` elements with some context, please?

Comment: @Matt: Sure, I updated the question with the surrounding HTML.

Comment: Even with your provided HTML, it still works. http://jsfiddle.net/r6C2p/

Comment: I just double checked it for about the fifth time, and it definitely does not work on my development machine. All the code/html is exactly the same as above. I may just have to chalk this one up to gremlins. :)

Comment: I hard coded the result variable HTML in my page, and it does work. The HTML for the result variable in the question is a copy and paste from the AJAX call though. Must be some glitch somewhere. I don't have time to debug further since the second method is working. I'll try to come back and update the question when I have more time. Thanks everyone for taking the time to offer your advice.

Comment: Oh yes, I almost forgot. I want to give a quick shoutout to the anonymous downvoter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would maybe try to update your jQuery version.

See this [example](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/a35fd.php)

I'm using jQuery 1.5 and it's working

EDIT: weird, [it works](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/a35fd2.php) with 1.4.4, too

I'd try to look on ajax result, if it's exactly same and you could also try to hardcore your ajax result

Comment: @karim79: `try to hardcore` - I see hardcore, am I missing something?